# when working with bulk volume system getting slow by c# window service

Tags: c#

here below i have pasted a c# code which i was using threading methodology in window service, on service initial time it was working proper after some process goin on the system was getting slow, some times i am recieving errors like system time out memory exeception kind of errors.

can any one suggest me whether my threading methodology is good or not? kindly suggest some suggestion

i m using timer event to it will fire for every three minutes --> (DueTime)

(CsvGenFromDatabase) --> this the method which i was calling in on start method , it will calls some sub methods in this

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {



            strNowDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

            timerjob.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(CsvGenFromDatabase);

            timerjob.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(DueTime);

            timerjob.Enabled = true;

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("my service started");

    }


 protected override void OnStop()
    {

            strNowDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("my service stopped");

    }

private void CsvGenFromDatabase(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) // Transaction Scope Started
            {

                Thread threadITD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForITD));  // Thread Initialize for ITD 


                Thread threadCTD = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForCTD));  // Thread Initialize for CTD 


                Thread threadCID = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForCID));  // Thread Initialize for CID 


                Thread threadFFM = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileGenerationForFFM));  // Thread Initialize for FFM



                try
                {
                    if ((threadITD == null) || (threadITD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) || (threadITD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted))
                    {
                        threadITD.Start();  // Thread Started for ITD 
                        //LogError(1, "Form1", "CsvGenFromDatabase", "ITD Thread Started", "ITD Thread Started");
                    }
                    if ((threadCTD == null) || (threadCTD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) || (threadCTD.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted))
                    {
                        threadCTD.Start(); // Thread Started for CTD 
                       // LogError(1, "Form1", "CsvGenFromDatabase", "CTD Thread Started", "CTD Thread Started");
                    }
                    if ((threadCID == null) || (threadCID.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) || (threadCID.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted))
                    {
                        threadCID.Start(); // Thread Started for CID 
                       // LogError(1, "Form1", "CsvGenFromDatabase", "CID Thread Started", "CID Thread Started");
                    }
                    if ((threadFFM == null) || (threadFFM.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped) || (threadFFM.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted))
                    {
                        threadFFM.Start(); // Thread Started for FFM
                        //LogError(1, "Form1", "CsvGenFromDatabase", "FFM Thread Started", "FFM Thread Started");
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    objErrorLog.SrtErrorText = ex.ToString().Substring(0, 25);
                    objErrorLog.StrErrorDescription = ex.ToString();
                    objErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(objErrorLog);
                }
                finally
                {
                    scope.Complete();

                }
            }


    }
```

Comment: Are you creating threads faster than the work can be processed?  You can check the thread count for your service and see if it continues to increase over time.

Comment: Also, in .NET you generally should avoid explicit creation of threads and use the thread pool API instead.

Comment: I disagree with Chris on subtle point. The thread pool manages the threads in a better fashion, but if one is not creating/destroying threads, then *rolling one* own threads will not lead to any significant loss.

Comment: private void CsvGenFromDatabase() {     timerjob.Stop();      //long running process      timerjob.Start(); } if i do like my problem will sort out ?

Comment: if i do like above comment until unless job A finished it will not start job B, hope wantedly we are stopping job B to start right ?

Answer (score 0):

Are the threads doing busy waiting?

In other words cycling through loops waiting for something to occur and burning cycles by such churning? One should put in logic to aviod such busy waiting when there is nothing to do. To do that simply do

Thread.Sleep(0);

which informs the CLR to give up the thread's timeslice to another thread which may actually need it and this thread will start again in the quickest fashion upon the start of its next cycle.